# The requested address is not valid in its context when listen data from other machine

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcp, tcplistener

hello i am using tcp ip communication using c# when my code listen from IP then its give me error message the requested address is not valid in its context. here is the code.

```
 TcpListener server = null;
        try
        {
            // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
            Int32 port = 5555;
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("10.3.0.234");

            // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
            server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

            // Start listening for client requests.
            server.Start();

            // Buffer for reading data
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
            String data = null;

            // Enter the listening loop.
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

                // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

                data = null;

                // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                int i;

                // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

                    // Process the data sent by the client.
                    data = data.ToUpper();

                    byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                    Console.WriteLine("Sent Data:" + msg);
                    // Send back a response.
                  //  stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                 //   Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);
                }

                // Shutdown and end connection
                client.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Stop listening for new clients.
            server.Stop();
        }
```

actually this ip is configured in machine where machine send results. actually i already seen many answers of same questions but i dont know where to change IPAddress.Any etc can any one give me answer by writing code how to communicate machine through tcp ip protocol thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the error

> The requested address is not valid in its context

Means that the *IP Address* given is not used by any network interface on your machine. In short you will probably just need to use [IPAddress.Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Exmaple**

```
server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
```

---

**Further reading**

[TcpListener Constructor (IPAddress, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6z86e63(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Initializes a new instance of the TcpListener class that listens for
>   incoming connection attempts on the specified local IP address and
>   port number.
>   **Remarks** If you do not care which local address is assigned, specify
>   [`IPAddress.Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any(v=vs.110).aspx) for the localaddr parameter, and the underlying service
>   provider will assign the most appropriate network address

[IPAddress.Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Provides an IP address that indicates that the server must listen for
>   client activity on all network interfaces.

Comment: ok actually when i use this code then no available status on machine can you tell me please can i send connect request?

Comment: `then no available status on machine` Please explain this more

Comment: actually when we start this code then status on lab machine which send result on ip and port status changed to available .its auto available when any connection established between client and server. machine is client and my machine is server.